# Need to create a PDF gallery in PHP with thumbnail

Tags: php, pdf, hyperlink, filenames, image-gallery

I have 110 PDF. These are named 001.pdf, 002.pdf [...] 110.pdf. I created all the thumbnail in JPG, called 001.jpg etc.

I created a table in PHP (below).

all the JPG are in ./files/alon/

all the PDF are in ./files/alon/pdf/

So

```
<img src=".' . $images . $file . '" />
```

is fine and everything works, but

```
<td align="center"><a href="' . $images . $big . $file . '">
```

is not working because $file is looking for 001.jpg in /pdf/ folder.

i need something like

```
<td align="center"><a href="' . $images . $big . $filename . '.pdf">
```

i would linke to use the same $filename to create a caption under every image 
"N° $filename"

here's my code

```
    $images = "./files/alon/"; 
    $big    = "pdf/";
    $cols   = 2;     

    if ($handle = opendir($images)) {   
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != rtrim($big,"/")) { 
          $files[] = $file; 
          rsort($files);
        } 
      } 
      closedir($handle); 
    } 

    $colCtr = 0; 
    echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="3"><tr>'; 

    foreach($files as $file) 
    { 
      if($colCtr %$cols == 0) 
      echo '</tr><tr><td colspan="2"><hr /></td></tr><tr>'; 
      echo '<td align="center"><a href="' . $images . $big . $file . '"><img src=".' . $images . $file . '" /></a></td>'; 
      $colCtr++; 
    }   
    echo '</table>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Please try to format your code properly the next time. It's not easy to read this way. I've done it for now.

Comment: Also try to rework your question - it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you replace extension of the file .jpg -->> .pdf  in a foreach($files as $file)  where you echo stuff on screen ?

```
foreach($files as $file) 
{ 
 $arrPDF = explode(".",$file);
 $pdfFile=$arrPDF[0]. ".pdf";
if($colCtr %$cols == 0) 
echo '</tr><tr><td colspan="2"><hr /></td></tr><tr>'; 
echo '<td align="center"><a href="' . $images . $big . $pdfFile . '"><img src=".' . $images . $file . '" /></a></td>'; 
      $colCtr++; 
}
```